# Unable to exit snowsql command prompt

Tags: macos, terminal, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, zsh

I am new to Snowflake. I must be missing something, because I am unable to exit the SnowSQL command prompt. According to the docs, and searching online, some combination of the commands `!abort` `!quit` and `!exit` should exit SnowSQL... but they do not seem to work.

```
Last login: Fri May 20 16:34:18 on ttys000
user@Users-MacBook-Pro ~ % snowsql
* SnowSQL * v1.2.21
Type SQL statements or !help
myusername#COMPUTE_WH@(no database).(no schema)>fldjafjdafjdas


                                                 !quit
                                                 !abort
                                                 !exit
```

My terminal is just stuck here and I have to exit the terminal window to shut it down.

How can I properly exit snowflake?

Comment: let me add that typing something like 'dfjklafafdasfa;' will resolve the query with an error and I can go about typing in more commands. But if I type in 'rdafdafadfafa' then hit 'Enter', then try to '!quit! then do ';', it does not resolve the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ctrl + C` to exit the current line.

Answer (score 4):

You have to start a new command line. So, we can type `Ctrl+C` and then in the new line to type `!quit`

Answer (score 0):

To quit the session easiest way is `CTRL+D`

But to exit the current line of code use `CTRL+C`